# Flutter/Firebase - When catching an error after adding a document in Firestore database a Native Error is returned instead of a FirebaseException

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, error-handling

### Description

I am working on error handling in my app and want to be specific in certain scenarios.

When adding a document to the Firestore database without the correct permissions I am expecting a **FirebaseException** but instead I get a **NativeError** Object. I am still able to convert it to a string and extract the error code, but I believe this is not ideal.

I am not sure why I get a Native Error or how I can fix it, and a google search is not giving me relevant information to solve the issue.

This might also be a bug since it is similar to the following issue for Web: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/pull/11258

### Example

Add a document without the correct permissions as defined by the rules

```dart
Future<String> addEvent(Event event) async {
    final eventRef = _db.collection('events').doc();

    event.id = eventRef.id;
    await eventRef.set(event.toJson())
        .then((value) => print('Success adding event!'))
        .onError((error, stackTrace) {
          print(error.runtimeType);
          print(error.toString());
    });

    return eventRef.id;
  }
```

Output
(Expecting FirebaseException instead of NativeError)

```
NativeError
FirebaseError: [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

Flutter Doctor

```
Flutter 3.16.5 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 78666c8dc5 (12 days ago) • 2023-12-19 16:14:14 -0800
Engine • revision 3f3e560236
Tools • Dart 3.2.3 • DevTools 2.28.4

Running flutter doctor...
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2861], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 16.11.30)
    X The current Visual Studio installation is incomplete.
      Please use Visual Studio Installer to complete the installation or reinstall Visual Studio.
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: I doubt the type of error matters too much here.  This looks like a typical rejection of a query due to security rules, so you should check that first.